# Chrome Extension popup.html html injection from with background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

currently i am using the chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener to call a method from crap.js everytime the icon is clicked and set up the popup page.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) { //Fired when User Clicks ICON

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        "file": "js/crap.js"
    }, function () { // Execute your code
        console.log("Script Executed .. "); // Notification on Completion
    });
     chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
    popup: "popup.html"
});

});
```

I have the following jquery code on content.js integrated in both scrip in popup.html and manifest.json

```
$( "p" ).append( "test" );
$( "#sectionA" ).html( "<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>" );
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I was wondering if it is possible to pass my values from select.js to content.js in the background to popup.html.

Also i have noticed that everytime i set up the popup html i am not able to call crap.js again. is there a workaround for this?

many thanks,
John